# Making my R function faster

Tags: r

**EDIT:** Sorry for the low quality post. I should have taken more time to present this to you. The post has been edited, I've added a working syntax example for the whole thing. Thank you to everybody who has offered advice so far.

**EDIT2:** Found that script is only slow on the other computer. Probably caused by some local issue, or the REPL.

I made this function. It produces frequency tables of values in a labelled (labelled & haven packages) data frame. It works, but I intend to use it on data frames with a lot of columns and I think it runs a bit slow; a user may think R has crashed when running it over 100+ columns, so I would like to speed it up.

The point of this script is to produce output that helps me look for processing errors in a survey dataset. It's a bit fiddly because I want to know about answer frequencies, and evaluate the shape of the value labels at the same time. So this script produces one frequency table per variable,  revealing frequencies, unused labels, and values without value labels. This will hopefully be clearer when looking at the output from the script.

I would be grateful if you could point out some ways to make this more efficient:

```
# demonstration dataset
library(knitr)
library(data.table)
library(labelled)

df <- data.frame(q1 = rep(1:6, 3), q2 = rep(6:1, 3))
val_labels(df[, c("q1", "q2")]) <- c(YES = 1, MAYBE = 2, NO = 3, DK = 4, MISSING=5)
val_label(df$q2, 1) <- NULL

# Produce a frequency table over values and labels in a labelled-class dataframe object
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Example:    freqlab(ds[[1]])    or    freqlab(ds[1:10])    or    freqlab(ds)
#    Wrong:      freqlab(ds[1])

freqlab <- function(x){

    # If the function is called on double brackets, eg. freqlab(ds[[11]])
    if (!is.list(x)){

        # Make a frequency distribution, put it in a data.table
        xFreq <- data.table(table(x))
        names(xFreq) <- c("Value", "Frequency")
        class(xFreq[[1]]) <- "numeric"
        setkey(xFreq, Value)

        # Put the value labels in another data.table
        if (!is.null(val_labels(x))){
            xLab <- data.table(val_labels(x), names(val_labels(x)))
            names(xLab) <- c("Value", "Label")
            setkey(xLab, Value)
        } else {
            # If the variable does not have labels, create one to avoid errors
            xLab <- data.table(xFreq[[1,1]], "** UNLABELLED **")
            names(xLab) <- c("Value", "Label")
            setkey(xLab, Value)
        }

        # Perform a FULL OUTER JOIN 
        outTable <- merge(xFreq, xLab, all = TRUE)

        # Arrange values in ascending order of absolute value
        outTable <- arrange(outTable, abs(outTable[[1]]))

        # Edit the Label column for value cases with no label
        outTable[[2]][is.na(outTable[[2]])] <- 0
        outTable[[3]][is.na(outTable[[3]])] <- "** UNLABELLED **"

        # If the output has more than 25 rows, cut it short
        if (dim(outTable)[1] > 25){
            outTable <- outTable[1:25]
        }

        # Output the table
        print(kable(outTable, format = "rst", align = "l"))


    # If the function is called on a list of variables, eg. freqlab(ds[10:11]),
    #   do the same steps as above, looping through all the input variables
    } else {

        for (y in 1:length(x)){

            xFreq <- data.table(table(x[[y]]))
            names(xFreq) <- c("Value", "Frequency")
            class(xFreq[[1]]) <- "numeric"
            setkey(xFreq, Value)

            if (!is.null(val_labels(x[[y]]))){
                xLab <- data.table(val_labels(x[[y]]), names(val_labels(x[[y]])))
                names(xLab) <- c("Value", "Label")
                setkey(xLab, Value)
            } else {
                xLab <- data.table(xFreq[[1,1]], "** UNLABELLED **")
                names(xLab) <- c("Value", "Label")
                setkey(xLab, Value)
            }

            outTable <- merge(xFreq, xLab, all = TRUE)
            outTable <- arrange(outTable, abs(outTable[[1]]))
            outTable[[2]][is.na(outTable[[2]])] <- 0
            outTable[[3]][is.na(outTable[[3]])] <- "** UNLABELLED **"

            if (dim(outTable)[1] > 25){
                outTable <- outTable[1:25]
            }

            # Extra information printed when function is called on a list of variables
            cat("Name:\t", names(x[y]),"\n")
            print(kable(outTable, format = "rst", align = "l"))           
            cat(rep("-", 80), sep='', "\n\n")
        }
    }
}
```

Example of output:

```
> freqlab(df)
Name:    q1


=====  =========  ================
Value  Frequency  Label
=====  =========  ================
1      3          YES
2      3          MAYBE
3      3          NO
4      3          DK
5      3          MISSING
6      3          ** UNLABELLED **
=====  =========  ================
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Name:    q2


=====  =========  ================
Value  Frequency  Label
=====  =========  ================
1      3          ** UNLABELLED **
2      3          MAYBE
3      3          NO
4      3          DK
5      3          MISSING
6      3          ** UNLABELLED **
=====  =========  ================
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You could try to profile it (with RStudio) to see what part you have to improve.

Comment: Regarding the large `for` loop, would it be possible to use an `apply` function instead ?

Comment: What does your function do?  If you want to make a frequency table into a data frame, why not just `as.data.frame(table(x))`?

Comment: Might wanna post this on code review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to help you without toy data, more simple code, and a clear explanation of input and output. Anyway, a first step is typically to profile your code in order determine the bottlenecks which consume time. See `?Rprof` for the the `Rprof()`-function which provides profiling information.

This small example illustrates how to use it:

```
square <- function (x) {
 Sys.sleep(3)
 return(x^2)
}

add <- function (x, y) {
 Sys.sleep(1)
  return(x + y)
}

complicatedFunction <- function(x, y) {
  res <- square(add(square(x), square(y)))
  return(res)
}

# Try to profile out "complicated" function
Rprof()  # Start of profiling
res <- complicatedFunction(2, 5)  # Function to profile
Rprof(NULL) # End of profiling
summaryRprof() # Show results
#$by.self
#            self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
#"Sys.sleep"      9.54      100       9.54       100
#
#$by.total
#                      total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
#"Sys.sleep"                 9.54    100.00      9.54      100
#"complicatedFunction"       9.54    100.00      0.00        0
#"square"                    9.54    100.00      0.00        0
#"add"                       6.58     68.97      0.00        0
#
#$sample.interval
#[1] 0.02
#
#$sampling.time
#[1] 9.54
```

Here you see how long time is spent inside the called functions of the function --- in this example `Sys.sleep` clearly takes up all the time. See `?summaryRprof` for more info on how to understand this output.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about Rprof. I tried it out on the same data that prompted this post, and found out that the long run time is a local problem on my other computer, probably because of how I'm running R there (sublime repl). It takes 1.62 seconds here, while the other PC it looked like sublime crashed every time I ran it.